# StencilJS: How to pass @Prop-Decorator to component over tab-routing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, stenciljs

I want to inherit the `@Prop() documentID: string;` from my component `page-home.tsx` to the component `page-turnier.tsx`. My app-routing in `app-root.tsx` is the following:

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'app-root',
  styleUrl: 'app-root.css',
  // shadow: true,
})
export class AppRoot {
  render() {
    return (
      <ion-app>
        <ion-router useHash={false}>
          <ion-route-redirect from="/" to="/home"></ion-route-redirect>
          <ion-route url="/home" component="page-home"></ion-route>
          <ion-route url="/turniername/:documentID" component="app-tabs">
            <ion-route url="/teilnehmer" component="tab-teilnehmer">
              <ion-route component="page-turnier"></ion-route>
            </ion-route>
            <ion-route url="/teams" component="tab-teams">
              <ion-route component="page-turnier-teams"></ion-route>
            </ion-route>
          </ion-route>
        </ion-router>
        <ion-nav></ion-nav>
      </ion-app>
    )
  }
}
```

The property `:documentID` does not reach the component `page-turnier`?! The log `console.log(this.documentID)` in the component `page-turnier` results `undefined`. How can I pass the Prop-Decorator over the `component="tab-teilnehmer"` to `component="page-turnier"`?

The direct inheritage to the component `app-tabs` works fine. But I don't know how to bring the `:documentID` into `page-turnier` where I need it?!